# Internet Explorer Background Repeat on container for floating elements

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I am attempting to build a gallery page for a website I am working on, Internet Explorer 8 compatibility is a must. After building the script out for the page, I take a look in internet explorer and run into this interesting issue. It seems that my background image is running fine until suddenly it just stops. I have no idea why this is happening. The "galleries" are generated on the fly using javascript, and have CSS applied to them.

A link to the site is: http://daverto.ipwn.me/2011/galleries.html

I appreciate any help I may get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a style to #cm

```
height:100%;
```